# Unblock Google Translate plugin

Tags: google-translate

I have scheme code as here:

```
<a href="fb link"><img src="facebook-img" class="fb"></a>
<a href="fb link"><img src="twit-img" class="twit"></a>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
                function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                    pageLanguage: 'en',
                    multilanguagePage: true,
                    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
                  }, 'google_translate_element');
                }
                </script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I want to make my translate become beside twitter image. I have to write `<div id="google_translate_element" style="dispay:inline;">` but google translate still in bottom of facebook and twitter image.
How can solve it?